# Limit Entire Regex to non consecutive decimals

Tags: regex

So, I'm making an email regex and all periods(.) have to be appended and prepended by non period(.). My current regex is allowing "steve..jobs@gmai.com" and I need some help

Currently I have:

```js
,(^[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\\-`.+~?{|}=*%\"]*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\\-`+~?{|}=*%\"]+[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\\-`+~?{|}=*%\"][@][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,6}$)
```

Rule

```
Before @ symbol
allowed characters
A-Z,
a-z,
0-9,
-!#$%&'*+/=`
{|}~?^
```

No limit on these chars,
`.` (dot) is allowed only if it is prefixed and suffixed by any of the above allowed chars

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first part of your regex

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\\-`.+~?{|}=*%\"]*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\\-`+~?{|}=*%\"]+
```

by

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\-`+~?{|}=*%\"]+\.?)*
```

If i decompose:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\-`+~?{|}=*%\"]+
```

matches at least one non dot character (i removed the `.`)

`\.?` matches at most one dot

Wrap everything between brackets and add * to match the pattern 0 or several times
Note that ?: means you don't want to capture the group between brackets

`steve.jobs@gmail.com` is matched

`steve..jobs@gmail.com` is not matched

`s.te.ve.jobs@gmail.com` is matched

`.s.te.ve.jobs@gmail.com` is not matched

`s.te.ve.job.s@gmail.com` is matched

`s.te.ve.job.s.@gmail.com` is not matched

Note : The final regex i tested is

```
(^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\-`+~?{|}=*%\"]+\.?)*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\\-`+~?{|}=*%\"][@][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,6}$)
```

Comment: How would I account for an email like:

s.te.ve.jo.b.s@gmail.com It's an ugly email to say the least, but is valid.

Comment: I modified my answer to match s.te.ve.jo.b.s@gmail.com / Basically, you just have to remove the  [a-zA-Z0-9!#$&(\\\)\\-`+~?{|}=*%\"]+ / you can use regex101.com to test it